# what's fails in this query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query only work when I have a reference in the table `wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_id` but when this is empty mysql_num_rows return 0

The query is:

```
  SELECT (SUM(wm_products_quantities.new_quantity) - SUM(wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_total) ) AS stock_restante, 
         wm_products_wall.nombre, 
         wm_products_wall.detalles, 
         wm_products_wall.price, 
         wm_products_wall.image_full, 
         wm_products_wall.fecha, 
         wm_products_wall.article_hashid
    FROM wm_products_wall,
         wm_products_quantities, 
         wm_purchased_products 
   WHERE wm_products_wall.categoria = '$new_rquery_xp' 
     AND wm_products_wall.article_hashid = wm_products_quantities.hashid_ref 
     AND wm_products_wall.article_hashid = wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_id 
GROUP BY wm_products_wall.article_hashid 
ORDER BY stock_restante ASC
```

How to build this query to work when I have no record in the table `wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_id`

Comment: What's the problem? When the table is empty, you have no row matching the query so you get 0.

Comment: What you need is a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `FROM wm_products_wall, wm_products_quantities, wm_purchased_products` means all three table are [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) with each other.(that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table and so on.)

You can let wm_products_wall LEFT JOIN with wm_purchased_products, so do wm_purchased_products.

```
SELECT 
(SUM(wm_products_quantities.new_quantity) - SUM(wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_total) ) AS stock_restante, 
wm_products_wall.nombre, wm_products_wall.detalles, wm_products_wall.price, 
wm_products_wall.image_full, wm_products_wall.fecha, 
wm_products_wall.article_hashid
FROM wm_products_wall
LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_products_quantities
  ON wm_products_wall.article_hashid = wm_products_quantities.hashid_ref 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_purchased_products
  ON wm_products_wall.article_hashid = wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_id
WHERE wm_products_wall.categoria = '$new_rquery_xp' 
GROUP BY wm_products_wall.article_hashid 
ORDER BY stock_restante ASC
```

Comment: +1: Also helpful: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: but !!!
(SUM(wm_products_quantities.new_quantity) - SUM(wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_total) ) AS stock_restante don't display any result.
wm_products_quantities.new_quantity = 885 and wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_total is null. what is wrong again
thank

Comment: Sorry, I haven't notice the comment. If table `wm_purchased_products` is empty, `SUM(wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_total)` result should be NULL, while a number minus NULL will get NULL.
So we can change stock_restante expression to 
`(IFNULL(SUM(wm_products_quantities.new_quantity),0) - IFNULL(SUM(wm_purchased_products.purchased_article_total),0)) AS stock_restante`